# sharing SQLite database information

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a question regarding my app. While I was doing search for sqlite database concepts and advantages, I found that SQLite is serverless or you don't have to deal with server when you using it.

My question is, if SQLite is serverless, how two or more devices can share information in my app between them without server?

Comment: By not using SQLite. Simply (...) use a remote database on a server through webservices.

Comment: Sqlite in android means it saves data locally! Example when whatsapp messages are saved and you can still access them even if when there is not internet!

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 0):

By wanting to share anything between devices you are creating a server/client scenario. i.e. Something is served from one device to a client, the other device.

SQLite is probably not the ideal solution as there is no client-server aspect included, so you'd have to write you own server and client code, which would very likely not be at all simple.

Firebase could be the simplest solution as it's a single SDK and is hosted/served by Google. [This link - Add Firebase to Your Android Project - may be of interest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001467%20|%20Firebase*%20Brand%20GENERIC%20|%20Global%20|%20en%20|%20Desk%2BTab%2BMobile%20|%20Text%20|%20BKWS%20[2017]&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=CjwKCAiAu4nRBRBKEiwANms5W5u0USwJWucKjR4kIGbScppRFnhZk8FxnkGH_H-bi1l1esMUzbK3whoC51QQAvD_BwE)